# Проблема со стандартной cpp библиотекой в Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, eclipse

При сборке проекта выдаёт ошибку Error: Program "make" not found in PATH. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?
[изображение 1](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-rMMSfb6QfcM/UqR4v36mOcI/AAAAAAAAADs/a0EHCYxARvI/w962-h549-no/1.png)[изображение 2](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-VF4YD8IpwXM/UqR4xrlOwEI/AAAAAAAAAD0/CJfEzck-yUA/w941-h549-no/2.png)

Comment: Сделать так, чтобы gcc и make были в PATH. Ваш КО.

P.S. Судя по картинкам оно ещё iostream найти не может, решение аналогичное.

Comment: нужно установить mingw, в котором будет и gcc, и make. Но как по мне, то эклипс под виндой - не самый лучший способ изучать программирование под с++.

Comment: Спасибо. А вы бы с чего начали?

Comment: мой путь - либо поставить studio express (она бесплатная и для начала хватит), либо поставить линукс, а там все это (gcc, eclipse и прочие) настраивается очень быстро.

Comment: Не подскажите как добавлять в PATH? Трудно нагуглить ответ на нубский вопрос по eclipse

Comment: посмотрите картинки здесь - http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/setting-up-windows-python-path-system-variable.php

хотя там на английском и для другого, но понятно.

Comment: KoVadim, спасибо за помощь!